# (MyClass) JavaScriptObject.createObject() vs. JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast()

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

**Are the following JSNI wrapper classes doing the same?**

```
public final MyClass extends JavaScriptObject {

   // ...

   private static MyClass createImpl() {
      return (MyClass) JavaScriptObject.createObject();  
   }

}
```

and

```
public final MyClass extends JavaScriptObject {

   // ...

   private static MyClass createImpl() {
      return JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();  
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of `JavaScriptObject.cast()` looks like this:

```
public final <T extends JavaScriptObject> T cast() {
  return (T) this;
}
```

So the answer is "yes", it is doing the same.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject.java?r=5303#116